# Validate parameters for function doesnt work for OU and CN

Tags: windows, validation, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to validate my OUs for a function with the following snippet

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [ValidateScript({Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $_ -Server $Domain})] 
    [String]$SourceOu
 )
```

This works for normal OUs like the following like a charm

```
"OU=Desktops,OU=Germany,DC=dom,DC=de")
```

But I also need to process the built in AD containers like these

```
"CN=Computers,DC=dom,DC=de",
```

Unfortunately they fail (maybe because their `distinguishedName` starts with CN and not with OU like for other OUs) with the error:

> Delete-OldADaccount : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SourceOu'. Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=Computers,DC=dom,DC=de' under: 'DC=dom,DC=de'.

Is there a way around this or can I just not check both types with one cmdlet? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just check that the object is a container?

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [ValidateScript({"container","organizationalUnit" -contains (Get-ADObject -Identity $_ -Server $Domain).ObjectClass})] 
    [String]$SourceOu
 )
```

EDIT: Ah. It should be container or organizationalUnit. Updated.

Comment: It works, but to be honest, I dont get it why ... can you explain the used syntax to me? :/ I dont understand that construct :(

Comment: Given my druthers, I would construct it:

Comment: Sorry. Didn't finish editing in time. The first part is an array. The "-contains" operator evaluates to true if the element that follows it appears in the array before it. The last part looks up the ad object and only returns the ObjectClass property. In PS 3+ you can switch them around and use the "-in" operator, which is more natural: (get-adobject $_).ObjectClass -in "organizationalUnit","container"

Comment: Ah ok, thx. I thought arrays would always have to be in {}, like in `$array = @{"organisationalUnit", "container}`. Thats why I was confused.